# Not receiving messages in TCP client/server program

Tags: c, client-server

I am trying to implement a tcp client and tcp server. I am able to establish the connection but when I send a message from the client, the server doesn't receive it and yes I did look at the previous posts and there were alot of similar problems. I did follow them but I am still getting the same error. The error i am getting is from server side:

```
recv: Socket operation on non-socket
```

Here is my code. If you can please let me know what I am doing wrong, I would really appreciate it. I think there is a problem in my server implementation.

Server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#define PORT 3490
#define BACKLOG 10

int main()
{
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    struct sockaddr_in dest;
    int status,socket_fd, client_fd,num;
    socklen_t size;

    char buffer[10240];
    memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
    int yes = 1;

    if ((socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))== -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Socket failure!!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (setsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
    memset(&dest,0,sizeof(dest));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
    if ((bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(struct sockaddr )))== -1)    { //sizeof(struct sockaddr) 
        fprintf(stderr, "Binding Failure\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((listen(socket_fd, BACKLOG))== -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Listening Failure\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(1) {
        size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);  

        if ((client_fd = accept(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &size)==-1)) {
            //fprintf(stderr,"Accept Failure\n");
            perror("accept");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Server got connection from client %s\n", inet_ntoa(dest.sin_addr));
        //buffer = "Hello World!! I am networking!!\n";

        if ((num = recv(client_fd, buffer, 10239,0))== -1) {
            //fprintf(stderr,"Error in receiving message!!\n");
            perror("recv");
            exit(1);
        }   

        // num = recv(client_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer),0);
        buffer[num] = '\0';
        printf("Message received: %s\n", buffer); 
        close(client_fd);   
        return 0;
        //close(socket_fd); 
    }    
}
```

Client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 3490

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in server_info;
    struct hostent *he;
    int socket_fd,num;
    char *buffer;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: client hostname\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((he = gethostbyname(argv[1]))==NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot get host name\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))== -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Socket Failure!!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&server_info, 0, sizeof(server_info));
    server_info.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_info.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    server_info.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)he->h_addr);
    if (connect(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_info, sizeof(struct sockaddr))<0) {
        //fprintf(stderr, "Connection Failure\n");
        perror("connect");
        exit(1);
    }

    buffer = "Hello World!! I am networking!!\n";
    if ((send(socket_fd,buffer, sizeof(buffer),0))== -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failure Sending Message\n");
        close(socket_fd);
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        printf("Message being sent: %s\n",buffer);
    }

    close(socket_fd);   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran the server under gdb, and discovered that client_fd is 0 after the call to accept().  This is an invalid socket fd, so I looked at that line of code and noticed that the closing parenthesis is wrong:

```
if ((client_fd = accept(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &size)==-1)) {
```

should be:

```
if ((client_fd = accept(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &size))==-1) {
```

Otherwise, it's doing the comparison first and then assigning the comparison to client_fd, whereas you want the assignment of the socket, followed by the comparison.

To avoid this exact kind of frustrating bug, it's generally considered best practice to not put assignments inside of 'if' statements.  I would recommend instead:

```
client_fd = accept(...);
if (client_fd < 0) { ... }
```

Also, in the client, the call to send() uses "sizeof(buffer)".  'buffer' is a char*, and the sizeof a pointer is 4 (on a 32-bit system), so only 'Hell' will be sent.  To send the full string, use "strlen(buffer)" instead for the amount to send.

Comment: yes, that was the error!! thank you!! i am receivig messages now but not the complete message
i wanted to send "Hello World!! I am networking!!" but all i received is "Hell"
any idea y??

Comment: Updated my answer to address the client send() issue.

Comment: oh u replied to my second problem!!! thank you so much!!! i really appreciate it!!!

Comment: this is my first implementation of a tcp client/server implementation. in order to learn more, what should i try now to get more understanding??

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is misplaced parentheses.

```
if ((client_fd = accept(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &size)==-1)) {
```

should actually be

```
if ((client_fd = accept(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &size))==-1) {
```

As you currently have it, `client_fd` will be assigned to the result of the equality test between the return value of `accept()` and `-1` and thus will always be zero in case of success.

This is one reason why many programmers avoid assignments in if statements. If written like this

```
client_fd = accept(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &size);
if (client_fd == -1) {
```

then the error can't occur.

Comment: sir, thank you so much!!! i got the mistake but u wrote the exact same statement as i did!! :P but i understood my mistake!!

Comment: Yes, just caught that and updated the answer. I copied and pasted the line and forgot to edit :)

Comment: but now, i am having another problem!! i am not able to receive the complete message!! :(
i want to send "Hello World!! I am networking!!"

Comment: but i only received: Hell
any idea y??

Comment: one quick ques abt the server side: there are two file descriptors....is it important to closr both file descriptors when closing the connection??